# 'regex not defined' error in fuzzy search

Tags: node.js

> regex not defined

Did some search it said use Regexp instead of regex but it gives me a database problem. What should i do to have fuzzy search in my website?

```
router.get("/", function(req, res){
    if(req.query.search){
       const regex = new RegExp(escapeRegex(req.query.search), 'gi');
    } else{
        // Get all campgrounds from DB
        Campground.find({name:regex}, function(err, allCampgrounds){
           if(err){
               console.log(err);
           } else {
              res.render("campgrounds/index",{campgrounds: allCampgrounds, page: 'campgrounds'});
           }

        });
    }
});
```

Comment: post your code (what you've tried)

Comment: what is you `req.query.search`? where is it coming from?

Comment: also `... .find({name:regex} ...` in this statement, where is `regex` coming from?